# Getting the data from redux. Why is my loading Screen not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add a loading screen to my functional component

I am fetching data from the redux.

Here is my `useEffect` Hook

```
const {addressList, replyMessage} = useSelector((state) => ({
    addressList: state.contactReducer.addressList,
    replyMessage: state.contactReducer.replyMessage,
  }));

useEffect(() => {
    async function anyNameFunction() {
      setLoading(true);
      await dispatch(fetchAddressList());
      
    }
    anyNameFunction();
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

As you can see I am awaiting dispatch then make setLoading false.

But when ever I try to render the component the loading screen section never comes up.
After the certain amount of time the data from redux are being rendered.
Why is that?

Here is my return JSX

```
<ScrollView>
      {loading && (
        <View
          style={{
            height: windowHeight,
            width: windowWidth,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginBottom: 50,
          }}>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
            <Text>Loading</Text>
          {/* <Loading /> */}
        </View>
      )}
      <View style={styles.landingContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.landingContainerImage}
          source={require('../../assets/images/AboutUs.jpg')}
        />
        <Text style={styles.landingText}>CONTACT RapidoBikes</Text>
      </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you function is async and the caller will not wait for example the code execution will continue inside the useEffect and your function anyNameFunction will have a different execution context. Try this

```
const {addressList, replyMessage} = useSelector((state) => ({
    addressList: state.contactReducer.addressList,
    replyMessage: state.contactReducer.replyMessage,
  }));

useEffect(() => {
    async function anyNameFunction() {
      setLoading(true);
      await dispatch(fetchAddressList());
      setLoading(false);
    }
    anyNameFunction();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please learn more about execution context in javascript for more insights on this

Comment: Still Not working But If I Wrapped `setTimeout(() => { setLoading(false)}, 500);`

Its Working

Comment: No need to wrap inside the setTimeout because the network call are dependant on many external factors. There could be something else which might not be working please share a codepen